# jQuery Appended boxes not draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jQuery UI code that allows an existing box to be draggable. When I append an additional box, however, those boxes are not draggable. Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MJKhq/4/
(the click me button adds another box to the document, but that box is not draggable like the first).
Here's also a code sample because it required me to:

```
$(function()
{
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
});

function makenew()
{
    $("body").append('<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content"> <p>Drag me around</p></div>');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every dom element must have unique id to work on or parent must have to be different. You can not use same id, more after appending it to dom bind event on it. You can define it like this.

```
<script>
function _bindEvents()
{
    $(".ui-widget-content" ).draggable();
}

$(function(){
    _bindEvents();
});

function makenew()
{
    $("body").append('<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content"> <p>Drag me around</p></div>');
    _bindEvents();
}
</script>
```

Comment: You still should not have id="draggable" in your makenew() function.

Comment: Yes it is used for stlying, @lawm you can remove and put styling in a class

Comment: Okay, thanks. Am I screwed if I want to remove a specific one of the appended things though? Should I use some sort of unique ID generator?

Comment: no classes can also be used but it is good to style with class not with id, you can use as many as classes to bind event.

Comment: I mean if I want to select a specific box to remove. Should I make each box have an ID that increments when it's created?

Comment: yes if you want to play with those dragable divs I would suggest you create id generator and assign id to each elements. Incremental ids will work too.

Comment: I just found that you can use a (this) selector as well somehow.

Answer (score 0):

There should be only one element with the same id in DOM tree.
By adding a new box you get two elements with same id.
Try using classes.

Answer (score 0):

Remember `id` must be unique, you can't use same `id` more than one element on the same page and in this case you can use `class` instead of `id`, like

```
function makenew() {
    var div=$('<div class="draggable ui-widget-content"><p>Drag me around</p></div>');  
    $("body").append(div);
    $(div).draggable();
}
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/MJKhq/8/).

Comment: You cannot have two class attributes in a tag. Merge the contents of them into 1 class attribute.

Comment: @3dgoo, Thanks! It was a mistake.